# Audio Chat Using Sockets

Tags: python

I'm trying to do an audio chatroom. I've been going through lots of tutorials but can't seem to make this work. I found this repository where I found examples of recording audio (I need this feature) and a basic text chat room.

The server-side code for chat, it also includes the needed code for audio recording:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, session, url_for, \
    current_app
from flask_socketio import emit
from socketio_examples import socketio
import uuid
import wave

bp = Blueprint('chat', __name__, static_folder='static',
               template_folder='templates')


@bp.route('/')
def index():
    """Return the client application."""
    chat_url = current_app.config.get('CHAT_URL') or \
        url_for('chat.index', _external=True)
    return render_template('chat/main.html', chat_url=chat_url)


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/chat')
def on_connect():
    """A new user connects to the chat."""
    if request.args.get('username') is None:
        return False
    session['username'] = request.args['username']
    emit('message', {'message': session['username'] + ' has joined.'},
         broadcast=True)


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/chat')
def on_disconnect():
    """A user disconnected from the chat."""
    emit('message', {'message': session['username'] + ' has left.'},
         broadcast=True)


@socketio.on('post-message', namespace='/chat')
def on_post_message(message):
    """A user posted a message to the chat."""
    emit('message', {'user': session['username'],
                     'message': message['message']},
         broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('start-recording', namespace='/audio')
def start_recording(options):
    """Start recording audio from the client."""
    id = uuid.uuid4().hex  # server-side filename
    session['wavename'] = id + '.wav'
    wf = wave.open(current_app.config['FILEDIR'] + session['wavename'], 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(options.get('numChannels', 1))
    wf.setsampwidth(options.get('bps', 16) // 8)
    wf.setframerate(options.get('fps', 44100))
    session['wavefile'] = wf


@socketio.on('write-audio', namespace='/audio')
def write_audio(data):
    """Write a chunk of audio from the client."""
    session['wavefile'].writeframes(data)


@socketio.on('end-recording', namespace='/audio')
def end_recording():
    """Stop recording audio from the client."""
    emit('add-wavefile', url_for('static',
                                 filename='_files/' + session['wavename']))
    session['wavefile'].close()
    del session['wavefile']
    del session['wavename']
```

The JS -file on the client-side:

```
var input_field = document.getElementById('message');
var chat_field = document.getElementById('chat');

// create a random username
var username = 'user' + parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);

var socketio = io.connect(location.origin + '/chat',
    {query: 'username=' + username, 'transports': ['websocket']});

// event handler when ENTER is pressed on the chat input field
input_field.onchange = function() {
    socketio.emit('post-message', { message: this.value });
    this.value = '';
}

// the server is sending a message to display in the chat window
socketio.on('message', function(message) {
    msg = document.createElement('p');
    if (message.user) {
        // this is a message written by a user
        msg.innerHTML = '<span class="user">' + message.user + '</span>: ' +
            '<span class="message">' + message.message + "</span>";
    }
    else {
        // this is a control message that comes from the server itself
        msg.innerHTML = '<span class="control-message">' + message.message + '</span>';
    }
    chat_field.appendChild(msg);
    chat_field.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight; // scroll to bottom
});

input_field.focus();
```

Is there some way to modify that chatroom to be used with live audio stream instead of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you would want to start with a project closer to what you are looking for - a voice chat program.

https://github.com/TomPrograms/Python-Voice-Chat